# Is it possible to create a ncat loop?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, netcat, remote-control

If you had two computers, wanting to control one from another using only ncat, without using telnet, ssh or other networking tools and only two shells, how could i go about that?

I have successfully done so with three shells:

1. `cat | ncat 192.168.0.11`
2. `ncat -l | bash | ncat 192.168.0.16`
3. `ncat -l`

Would it be possible to have one shell, where the input from one ncat would get displayed on the screen and the input in the shell would get piped into the other ncat?

So far I have run into the following problems:

1. Before a ncat can start sending data, another ncat has to be listening for it, so I need a way to force a ncat to send data anyways.
2. If I did something like `ncat -l | cat | ncat 192.168.0.11`, the data would just get looped right back into the sending ncat (which I don't want), and wouldn't get displayed on the screen (which I want) and the input from the keyboard would just get ignored (which I also don't want). Maybe the first two problems could be solved by somehow redirecting the received data to stderr, but how would I capture KB input?

It doesn't matter in which shell such a manouver would be possible, just that it works (fish, bash, zsh, anything is fine).

This is not a serious scenario, I am just curious.

Comment: Am I reading this right: Your main problem is redirecting both `stdin` and `stdout`/ `stderr` of a shell to `ncat`?

Answer (score 0):

To be clear: in this answer "local" means the machine where you run (1), "remote" means the machine where you run (2).

On the remote machine, instead of (2) run `ncat -e /bin/bash` or maybe `ncat -c 'exec /bin/bash -i 2>&1'`; you don't need (3) locally then. These options are exactly designed to run something and connect its stdin and stdout to the network connection.

And I think you don't need `cat` in (1) anyway. On the local machine sole `ncat 192.168.0.11` should work.

Note the solution does not allocate a tty on the remote side. By typing locally you can make the remote shell run a command that tries to interact with the terminal. Such command will not fail, it will find a terminal, but it will be the terminal of this `ncat` invoked in (2). On the other hand a command that expects its stdout or stdin to be a terminal may refuse to work.

Also don't expect local <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to get to the remote side and cause SIGINT there.

For comparison: `ssh` (or rather `sshd` on the remote side) can allocate a tty. It does this (and more) by default, if you don't specify a remote command. It does this to allow you to work interactively in a remote shell as if it was local. Our contraption does nothing similar.